# I didn't get what is the Research assistant badge

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki, help-center

So this is what the so called `Research Assistant` says it's requirement are:

> Edit 50 tag wikis

I edited 2 tag's description and got approved where my reputation was increased by 2 each saying:

> +2 reputation: [tag-name] tag wiki excerpt
>
> +2 reputation: [tag-name] tag wiki excerpt

So when I checked my Research Assistant badge requirements, there was written you've edited `0/50` tag wiki's.

Please can someone explain me what's it all about and where am I wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The tag excerpt and tag wiki are different things:

[image: tag excerpt at the top, wiki at the bottom]

The research assistant badge is for editing the tag WIKI. For only providing an excerpt, you won't make progress on that badge.

Just do know that the excerpt and wiki need to explain when to use the tag on a post. They are not an advertisement for the topic of the tag and certainly not a plagiarized copy-paste from a wikipedia or product website.

With that said I assume you agree that your revision of the excerpt on [blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4992338/4) isn't actually explaining for which questions the tag is appropriate. It is the blurb that you copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_(service)) without attribution. That is called plagiarism and is not okay. Please don't do that for the edits you plan to make on these excerpts and wikis.

Comment: upvoted for freehand circle (the second one only, I felt the first one was too small).